# Cannot update windows phone 8 project by using Phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I create a Windows Phone 8 project by using [PhoneGap CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).

I successfully build the project by calling **`phonegap build wp8`**. However, I have some trouble with updating the project.

```
C:\Users\stan\Desktop\CordovaLibraryProject>phonegap platform update wp8
[phonegap] updating Windows Phone 8 platform...
   [error] Update script failed: Error: Command failed: Cannot read non-existant
 file : C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\VERSION
Cannot read non-existant file : C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\w
p8\VERSION
```

The fact is "VERSION" is actually under `C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0`. I tried to manually move it to `C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8`. Then I got a new error.

```
C:\Users\stan\Desktop\CordovaLibraryProject>phonegap platform update wp8
[phonegap] updating Windows Phone 8 platform...
   [error] Update script failed: Error: Command failed: Error : Could not copy f
ile/folder because it doesn't exist.
      File/Folder : C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\templates
\standalone\cordova
Error : Could not copy file/folder because it doesn't exist.
      File/Folder : C:\Users\stan\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\templates
\standalone\cordova
```

There is no folder named standalone under `C:\Users\ss13216\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\templates`

After that I gave up.

Is that a bug in PhoneGap or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi problem is with android sdk.

Ensure you are using adt-bundle-windows and set following environment path.

Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Environment variables -> System variables

ANDROID_HOME: C:\Nithi\software\Android_sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt- bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\

path: "Existing path";%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

"Existing path": already system paths will be there.

delete .cordova and .android in C:\Users\youruser>

close command prompt and open.

phonegap run android or cordova platform add android

hope with will work!!!!